# threading.Condition C API

Tags: python, multithreading, cpython, python-c-api, condition-variable

Is there a [`threading.Condition`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html#condition-objects)-like object exposed directly in the [Python C API](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/index.html)? If not, what are my options?

Comment: Do you need to expose it to Python code also?

Comment: @JanneKarila: Nope. I just need to use it from C, preferably avoiding dict lookups for methods and such.